# Can't open port on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: linux, networking, centos, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have an API which I successfully hosted on Amazon AMI instance. I know that's for sure because I can use it locally using curl. Api hosted on port 8080.

That's what I putted into cmd for open port:

```
su
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
/etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

I turned the firewall off as well:

```
service iptables save
service iptables stop
chkconfig iptables off
```

That's how my out/in rules looks in AWS console:
[image]
[image]

And I still can't reach my app via server public IP from outside.
Why that's happening?

**UPDATE**

Result for `/sbin/iptables -L` :

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**UPDATE 2**

`netstat -ltpn` result:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3941/uwsgi
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58704               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::45589                    :::*                        LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      -
```

Comment: Have a look to _Network ACL_ and _Route tables_ under VPC Dashboard.

Comment: What is the error message you get from outside ?

Comment: What's the output of /sbin/iptables -L?

Comment: @Thetimehascome I trying to check port state via telnet and I get "Could not open connection to the host, on port 8080: Connect failed"

Comment: @Berlin I've added result for this command into my question

Comment: Can you run netstat -ltpn command to check what services are listening on the instance? Can you try to run tcpdump -n -i NET_IFACE port 8080 to see if traffic is coming in? Can you ssh to the instance over the public IP?!?

Comment: Ensure that you are connecting to the correct IP address.

Comment: @Thetimehascome yes, I completely sure

Comment: @dsmsk80 I've updated question.

Comment: @dsmsk80 that's what I see after tcpdump command and trying to send from outside request to my application:
https://codeshare.io/GLjbB6

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the `netstat` output, it seems that your app is listening on loop-back interface only - `127.0.0.1:8080` and so you are not able to connect to it outside of the instance.

See e.g. `ssh` service - `0.0.0.0:22`. This means the service is listening on "all network interfaces".

You need to reconfigure your application to make it listening not only on loop-back.

Another solution could be to add `iptables DNAT` rule so incoming requests are forwarded to the loop-back interface.

Comment: It's odd that the OP isn't getting `Connection Refused` which is normally diagnostic of this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the security group associated with the Instance that you have deployed and make sure that it allows inbound traffic on port 8080. both the Network ACL and the security group need to allow the traffic.

you can find more information on security groups here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html