# Can't able to open custom port in centos 7 launch AWS

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-ec2, centos7

I have looked to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/840833/cant-open-port-on-amazon-ec2-instance?newreg=631eaaeb0c5041c992040c166c5a336b) issue and notice when he ran netstat -ltpn he do have the 8080 port entry but in my case the desire port 8069 is not entered in this list.

Here was my step till now

```
sudo yum install firewalld -y
sudo systemctl start firewalld
sudo systemctl enable firewalld
sudo systemctl status firewalld
```

The output of the status is :

```
    ● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2018-11-11 09:02:38 UTC; 6min ago
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
 Main PID: 27702 (firewalld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/firewalld.service
           └─27702 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid

Nov 11 09:02:37 ip-172-31-29-154.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Start...
Nov 11 09:02:38 ip-172-31-29-154.us-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Start...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full
```

then I tried to open open port 8069:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8069/tcp --permanent
sudo systemctl stop firewalld
```

also I have added the inbound port 8069 in aws security group
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FC4kV.png)

Here is the output of `netstat -ltpn`

```
[root@ip-172-31-29-154 ~]# netstat -ltpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      471/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1088/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      954/master
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      471/rpcbind
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1088/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      954/master
```

And when I tried to run command in window command prompt

```
telnet "host public IP" 8069
```

then it say

```
Connecting To "host public IP"...Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no service configured to respond on port 8069.

netstat shows only ports with services listening (waiting for requests) on these. With telnet it is the same, you can't just connect to any port and expect a response.

You have to find out how to configure the service that you are expecting to listen on that port to actually listen there.

**And:** If you enable a firewall you have to make absolutly sure that your SSH-Port (22) is allowed because otherwise you might shut yourself out!

Comment: Thanks, I think I made mistake while installing application, your hint was very helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help!